# Java .split weird outcome

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm trying to split up a string, but it doesn't seem to give the correct output
this is the string being passed around

```
1#0:250:250:
```

I first do this

```
String[] dataArray = data.split("#");
```

this gives me

```
1
0:250:250:
```

I then do this

```
for( int i = 0; i < totalPlayers; i++)
            {
                String[] pos = dataArray[i++].split(":");
                if( Integer.parseInt( pos[0] ) == ID )
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                assets[i].setPosition( Integer.parseInt( pos[1] ),     Integer.parseInt( pos[2] ) );
                }
            }
```

I get an error saying ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, if i print out pos[0] i get 1, if i print out pos[1] i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,
Why isn't my string being split up into

```
0
250
250
```

?

Cheers

Canvas

Comment: In the first iteration of your for loop, `dataArray[i++]` evaluates to `dataArray[0]` which is `"1"`, which doesn't split on `:`.

Comment: You are incrementing the counter several times  - did you mean `String[] pos = dataArray[1].split(":");` ?

Comment: dataArray is split using "#", so dataArray[0] = 1, dataArray[1] = 0:250:250:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code that is causing it to split `1` instead of `0:250:250:` . Recall that the postfix increment operator (e.g. `i++`) increments the variable *after* it is used in the expression. So the first line in the loop is really saying `String[] pos = dataArray[i].split(":"); i = i + 1;` .

The simple fix would be to change `i++` to `++i`, which would essentially make the line run as `i = i + 1; String[] pos = dataArray[i].split(":");` . However, this exact bug is why using `++` operators inside complex statements can be confusing and is often discouraged. Moreover, incrementing your loop variable outside of your `for` statement can lead to additional confusion.

Since the idea you really want to express is 'loop through the array by pairs', I would recommend writing something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalPlayers; i += 2) {
    String[] pos = dataArray[i + 1].split(":");
    // (the same as above)
}
```

Comment: Yep, i just tried the i + 1 and it works, cheers for that information which i didn't know :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first time, `i` will be `0`. That essentially means `dataArray[0]`, which is `1`. Hence, when you do this:-

```
String[] pos = dataArray[i++].split(":");
```

Your `pos` has only 1 element in the array **(i.e.)** `pos[0]` which is `1`. Therefore, if you try to access `pos[1]` or `pos[2]`, you'll get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I just tried "String[] pos = dataArray[i].split(":");" and the data from pos[1] which should be 250 is actually 0:250:250:

Comment: I just tried what you tried, and I got exactly what I've mentioned above in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

pos is created twice, once with only 1 as an element. the second time it will have 0, 250, 250.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is due to the fact that the split function takes a regular expression (regex).

Because the colon is a special character in regex, you must escape it with a backslash.

In Java, you must escape a backslash with another backslash.

So, try splitting on "\\:" instead of just ":"